# TypeError: Dog() takes no arguments

Tags: python, function, class

Where is the mistake? I did everything the same as in the video tutorial / book, there does not give an error. Maybe of course there is another version of python. What's my mistake?

```
class Dog():
    """Simple dog model"""

    def _init_(self,name, age):
        """Initialize attributes, name and age"""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        """Dog created"""
        def sit(self):
            """The dog will sit down on command"""
            print(self.name.title()+ " the dog sat down")


        def jump():
            """The dog will jump on command"""
            print(self.name.title()+" the dog jumped")


my_dog = Dog()
print(my_dog.name)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/thebasics/exmplclass.py", line 22, in <module>
    my_dog = Dog('topik',5)
TypeError: Dog() takes no arguments
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `_init_` should be `__init__`

Comment: Are you sure the code you have here is 100% identical to the code you're running? Because your error message contains the line `my_dog = Dog('topik',5)`, which isn't anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, I tried to change the attributes and copied the wrong. Thank you so much!